# How do I view local storage and session storage using capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara, google-chrome-headless, poltergeist

I'm doing some analysis to confirm what data is being stored on the client by various interactions with some websites. 
I'd like to automate this using Capybara (and Poltergeist / headless chrome).
I can get the cookies using

```
@session.driver.cookies
```

Is there a way to do something similar for any local storage and session storage likewise? Scanning through the docs but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poltergeist and headless chrome are different things. Poltergeist is obsolete/discontinued at this point in time, but if you're using headless chrome via the selenium driver you can access them as

```
@session.driver.browser.local_storage
@session.driver.browser.session_storage
```

Note: This is selenium driver specific - the only cross driver method would be to access them via `evaluate_script`

Comment: Hi, aware Poltergeist is not supported anymore, just happens that I had a load of stuff done in poltergeist (planning to move to headless chrome but still haven't gotten around to it).
Tried the above and can confirm they don't work with Poltergeist. Let me have a go with headless chrome and see if we have more luck.

Comment: @Carpela Yes - for any driver other than Selenium you're probably going to have to use `@session.evaluate_script(...)` to run JS that accesses the keys of session or local storage you're interested in (which is basically what Selenium does when you call the methods shown in the answer too)